# Refused to execute a script - X-XSS-Protection in safari

Tags: safari, http-headers, xss, content-security-policy

Helllo,

Recently I got this error in console:

> The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in  because its source
>   code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled because the
>   server did not send an 'X-XSS-Protection' header.

I was reading the questions here telling about getting the same response. But I dont think it is my issue. Here is what I got:

Admin panel -> Edit product (example.com/admin/produkty/upravit/10)

- text inputs
- textareas + ckeditor
- ckfinder

After submitting the form (form action: example.com/admin/produkty/upravit/10)

- I put everything into DB and then do redirect to (example.com/admin/produkty/zobrazit)

I dont see any similarities between the asked questions here.

Whats more I get it only at few products. Some are working OK some are not but there is no  or any other html tags.

Whats even MORE I got it at dev subdomain and it is working ok there. So I am out of ideas....

Just one more test: It is doing only in safari. Working on chrome without problems

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `X-Xss-Protection` header to specify how the auditor should behave. Possible values to set:

```
X-Xss-Protection    1; mode=block;
X-Xss-Protection    1
X-Xss-Protection    0
```

Depending on your needs you may consider disabling it, which is the last option, but be aware of the security implications of disabling the XSS Auditor.

Comment: I dont see reason why it gets blocked. If I edit other product it is ok. So I am confused. Further more it is misbehaving in safari. At chrome it is ok